# python string contains and string is equal to

Tags: python, r, grepl

I have this r code that I need to translate to python. so for grepl, I would use the str.contains but can I add str is equal to in the same line? basically, how would you put this in one sentence?

```
rank <- subset(rankings, grepl("o",type) | grepl("v",type) | grepl("fs",type) 
                   | type == "kp" |  type == "paa" | type == "tb" | type== "ts, thumb")
```

Answer (score 0):

One method would be to `join` the `list` of patterns with `|`, use that in `contains` on the 'type' column, OR (`|`) use the `isin` for fixed string match on a list of elements

```
rankings[(rankings['type'].isin(['kp', 'paa', 'tb', 'ts, thumb'])) |
          (rankings['type'].str.contains("|".join(["v", "fs", "o"])))]
```

-output

```
#   type
#0  kp
#2  paa
#3  tb
#5  ts, thumb
#7  v1
#8  fs2
#9  orange
```

---

In `R`, the OP's code can be simplified as

```
subset(rankings, grepl("o|v|fs", type)| 
             type %in% c("kp", "paa", "tb", "ts, thumb"))
```

#### data

```
import pandas as pd
rankings = pd.DataFrame({"type":["kp", "5g", "paa", "tb", "ta", "ts, thumb", "ta1", "v1", "fs2", "orange", "efz"]})
```